# use express route in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my app.js I do

```
var routes = require('./routes');
app.use('/books', routes);
```

and then in my route folder I do

```
router.get('/books', function(req, res){
    res.render('book/index');
});
```

to render my view, where I have a folder call book and there's an index.handlebars within it. I see nothing wrong with above logic but I didn't see any view being rendered in my case,where's my mistake?

Comment: Try `/books/books/` as the adress in your browser

Comment: @adeneo nope doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure the view is called `index.js`? If so, try using `res.render('book/index.js')` (explicitly name the extension)

Comment: @robertklep how can my view be a js file? it's dot handlebars

Comment: @AmyGlenn _"I have a folder called book and there's an index.js within it"_ confused me.

Comment: @robertklep typo sorry.

Comment: @AmyGlenn so what exactly do you get as a response? An error, a particular HTTP status code, just an empty page?

Comment: @robertklep not found. if I do `app.use('/', routes);` and declare the second block in index.js it work without any problem. But how can I separate it out?

Comment: If you use `app.use('/books', router)`, your router shouldn't _also_ use `/books` because that creates a route for `/books/books` (that was what @adeneo was hinting at). Try using `router.get('/', ...)` and keep your `index.js` the same.

Comment: @robertklep I got adeneo's point but why it still not found?

Comment: @adeneo you may have to add a bit more context in that case (for instance, how exactly are you instantiating `router` and passing it back to the main app, and also if you have other routes or middleware in use)

Comment: @robertklep I shared my files with you : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5O1qOQ7MVcPNkplVk1Da1VUZWs/view?usp=sharing take a look how can I create more routes file in routes folder.

Comment: @AmyGlenn I don't see any reference to `/books` there?

Comment: @robertklep that is just the miniature I create for this question. can u seperate my route in routes/index.js to have like order.js, catalog.js etc? now there're all inside that index.js which is bad.

Comment: @AmyGlenn https://gist.github.com/robertklep/4611b279bcbd2052f5af

Comment: @robertklep ah so it was the `use` issue? why it doesn't work when I do `router.use('/order', routes);`? the second param default point to index?

Comment: @AmyGlenn `routes` only exists in `app.js`, not in `routes.js`, which is where `router` exists. So I'm confused :-)

Comment: @robertklep no `routes` is a variable exsited in app.js, `var routes = require('./routes');
`

Comment: @AmyGlenn that's what I'm saying :-)

Comment: @robertklep tq so much for helping, now I understand my problem. Do u know any method/way where I can get expert help to improve my programming? sometime I stuck for days which is no good for my progress haha.

Comment: @AmyGlenn perhaps https://www.codementor.io can be useful

Comment: @robertklep where should I include this line `router.use('/order', require('./order'));
` ? router.js?

Comment: @AmyGlenn in your existing `routes/index.js`, instead of the current route for `/order` that's there.

Comment: @robertklep I do it this way in my app.js `var order_routes = require('./routes/order');
routes.use('/order', order_routes);` it worked too.